# Implement 2D matrix from classes C++

Tags: c++, oop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++ and currently I'm trying to implement 2D matrix from classes, this is my current code, right now I'm unable to create an instance of the matrix object, please leave me feedback what I need to fix.

*Updated: I have fixed some of the code, but the matrix doesn't print anything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(); //Default constructor
        Matrix(int *row, int *col); //Main constructor
        void setVal(int row, int col, int val); //Method to set the val of [i,j]th-entry
        void printMatrix(); //Method to display the matrix
        ~Matrix(); //Destructor

    private:
        int row, col;
        double **matrix; 

        //allocate the array
        void allocArray()
        {
            matrix = new double *[*row];
            for (int count = 0; count < *row; count++)
                *(matrix + count) = new double[*col];
        }
};

//Default constructor
Matrix::Matrix() : Matrix(0,0) {}

//Main construcor
Matrix::Matrix(int *row, int *col)
{   
    allocArray();
    for (int i=0; i < *row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            *(*(matrix + i) + j) = 0;
        }
    }
}

//destructor
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
        delete [] *(matrix + i) ;
    delete [] matrix;
}

//SetVal function
void Matrix::setVal(int row, int col, int val)
{
    matrix[row][col] = val;
}

//printMatrix function
void Matrix::printMatrix()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cout << *(*(matrix + i) + j) << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int d1 = 2;
    int d2 = 2;

    //create 4x3 dynamic 2d array
    Matrix object(&d1,&d2);

    object.printMatrix();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should review the [C++ FAQ for Matrix.](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+FAQ+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
Matrix object = new int **Matrix(d1,d2);
```

is wrong. Use simply

```
Matrix object(d1,d2);
```

no need for Java-like syntax which in fact in C++ means dynamic allocation: `Matrix* object = new Matrix(d1,d2);`

Comment: I tried to compile it using online IDE but got this error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

code: http://goo.gl/Nixxen

Comment: @Capser First step is to make it compile. Segfault usually comes from bad allocation/accessing out of bounds. Try debugging your code and make sure your pointers are valid and you're allocating memory for them. In particular, in the constructor, you should first invoke `allocArray()` (think about the parameters `m` and `n`, basically you have to set them by your constructor), and only after initialize `p`. You are doing it in reverse now, so you first write in memory that's not yours, and only after allocate memory.

Comment: I've fixed it, the error went away but there is no output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Matrix object = new int **Matrix(d1,d2);` use `Matrix* object = new Matrix(d1,d2);`
Also, you will have to use `object->printMatrix();` instead of `object.printMatrix();`